# Conditional starting with "had"

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence correct?

> Had I had a lamp, I would have had light.

Comment: Is this an exercise or test you have been given and, if so what is the question?

Comment: It’s been a few days now, and there’re no another in coming answer. Trying editing some contexts in your question will make your question active again. And if there was a correct answer for your question, please marked an answer as correct (the green check image) on It.

Comment: I'm flagging this question for closure: proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Is there a better way to write this passage?") are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified and you include the research you've done. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 5):

There is a conditional clause without 'if'. In this case we use an inverted order of words /like in yes-no questions/. So the sentence is grammatically correct.

Answer (score -7):

When you begin a sentence with [an auxiliary verbs](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs), it will become a question or an interrogative sentence.

Your sentence is grammatically correct, **except** there is **`one thing`** needed to be changed.

> **Had I had a lamp? I would have had light.**

*- The first sentence means `you're asking yourself whether at that moment in the past you have a lamp or not.`*

*- The second sentence means `you want light, but you don't have it at that moment in the past`*

Comment: Here is a lesson you should study: http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/conditional_sentences09.html

Comment: You mean me or the OP? @michael.hor257k

Comment: I mean you. Your answer is baseless.